# In an electron js application load html template in an iframe after generating executable with electron-forge

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a simple electronjs application, which basically shows html content (an entire template with scripts, css, etc.) in an iframe (property src pointing to index.html), but I do it through electron dialog by selecting templates compressed in zip and using DecompressZip (decompress-zip, which is an npm dependency) I decompress it in a folder inside the project.
And from there I show the different html contents in the iframe, in the src property I use an absolute path to the index.html of each content using __driname. Everything works well in development but when I already generated the executable (Use electrong-forge, command npm run make) and I run the program with the .exe the html content is not shown, everything else works fine, the template is decompressed perfectly, but at the moment of showing in the iframe is the problem and within the iframe the following appears:
[Error que se muestra en el iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9klAZ.png)

The path to index.html is fine and I know that the error is because the html content that I have loaded into the application has not been precompiled and that's obvious because I load the html at run time, in production mode.
Question Is there any way to precompile at run time (in production)? o In some way ignore the directory where I host the html so that precompilation is not necessary and the content can be displayed? or what other solution could there be for this inconvenience?
I will be very grateful, since I have invested many things and I do not resolve it yet.

My json package is the following, the scripts and the electron-forge config:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",    
    "forge-start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make"
  },
"config": {
    "forge": {
      "make_targets": {
        "win32": [
          "squirrel"
        ],
        "darwin": [
          "zip"
        ],
        "linux": [
          "deb"
        ]
      },
      "electronPackagerConfig": {
        "packageManager": "npm"
      },
      "electronWinstallerConfig": {
        "name": "Estanteria"
      },
      "electronInstallerDebian": {},
      "electronInstallerRedhat": {},
      "github_repository": {
        "owner": "",
        "name": ""
      },
      "windowsStoreConfig": {
        "packageName": "",
        "name": "Estanteria"
      }
    }
  }
```

And the structure of the project (being the resources folder where the html templates are hosted):
[Estructura del proyecto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNYBI.png)

It should be mentioned that in the error image that is shown, inside the resources folder is what is decompressed: resources/7/34f927/index.html and the index that is read within 34f927 for this example.

Comment: Hello! You should edit your question to include this information-

Comment: Ready @OneLunchMan  I have included it in the Question.